# React Native allow keyboard to cover sticky footer

Tags: react-native

I need a layout with a sticky footer.
So, I created something like:

```
<View>
  <ScrollView>
   ....
  </ScrollView>
  <View> 
    //this is the footer
  </View>
</View>
```

However, in the ScrollView I have some TextInput elements, and when the keyboard is displayed it always pushes the footer up so that its just above the keyboard.

I want to allow the keyboard to cover the contents of the footer.
Any idea how that can be achieved?
Thanks!

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but maybe someone will get some ideas from this. I was also struggling with the similar problem that described above. What I ended up doing is following. Using [react-native-keyboard-spacer](https://github.com/Andr3wHur5t/react-native-keyboard-spacer) I managed to catch keyboard events and when the keyboard was open I hid the footer and showed it again when the keyboard was closed.